# MySQL error message: "1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'inf' in 'field list'"

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector

```
"errorMessage": "1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'inf' in 'field list'"
```

I'm not sure where the source of this error message is.
It points to `mycursor.executemany(sql, all_data)`, which tells me something is wrong with the data??
First, I'm trying to understand what this means. Can someone break it down?

The script is rather extensive but I show the portion where data is inserted.

```
                    # Create DataFrame
                df = pd.DataFrame({"date": date, "open": open, "high": high, "low": low, "close": close, "volume": volume})
                dfvol = pd.DataFrame({"date": date, "open": open, "high": high, "low": low, "close": volume, "volume": volume})

                df["sma10"] = SMA(df, 10)
                df["sma30"] = SMA(df, 30)
                df["sma50"] = SMA(df, 50)
                df["sma200"] = SMA(df, 200)
                df["rsi"] = RSI(df)
                df["williams"] = WILLIAMS(df)
                df["adx"] = ADX(df)
                df["bbwidth"] = BBWIDTH(df)
                df["vol10"] = SMA(dfvol, 10)
                df["vol30"] = SMA(dfvol, 30)

                LIST = [
                    float(df.tail(1)['sma10']), 
                    float(df.tail(1)['sma30']), 
                    float(df.tail(1)['sma50']), 
                    float(df.tail(1)['sma200']), 
                    float(df.tail(1)['rsi']),
                    float(df.tail(1)['williams']), 
                    float(df.tail(1)['adx']), 
                    float(df.tail(1)['bbwidth']),
                    float(df.tail(1)['vol10']),
                    float(df.tail(1)['vol30']),
                    float(df.tail(1)['close']),
                    yearPer,
                    monthPer,
                    fiveDayPer
                ]

                q = 0; NEW = []
                for K in LIST:
                    if math.isnan(K) == True:
                        NEW.append(0)
                    else:
                        NEW.append(K)
                    q += 1

                NEW.append(k[j])
                LIST.append(k[j])


                all_data.append( 
                    tuple( 
                    NEW
                    )
                    )

            except:
                pass
                

        j += 1  # going to the next ticker
    
    # this controls the amount of requests per second
    end = time.time()
    while end-start < 1.01:
        end = time.time()

print("total time to get data and make calculations: ",time.time() - Start_time)
print()

var = ['sma10','sma30','sma50','sma200','rsi','williams','adx','bbwidth','avgVol10day','avgVol30day','price','yearPer','monthPer','fiveDayPer'] # variable that we are updating
 
# table to insert into
table = 'stockStats_dev'
sql = UpdateBulk(var, table, 'ticker')

# # inserting the data into the table
mycursor.executemany(sql, all_data)

# closing access to the database
mydb.commit()
mycursor.close()
mydb.close()
```

Here is the full error message

```
[ERROR] ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'inf' in 'field list'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/index.py", line 422, in handler
    mycursor.executemany(sql, all_data)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 659, in executemany
    self.execute(operation, params)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 551, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 490, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
```

Describing the table

```
[('ticker', 'varchar(16)', 'NO', 'PRI', None, ''),
 ('companyName', 'varchar(255)', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('exchangeShortName', 'varchar(12)', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('sector', 'varchar(100)', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('industry', 'varchar(100)', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('description', 'blob', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('website', 'blob', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('news', 'blob', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('marketCap', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('enterpriseValue', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('price', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('52wkHigh', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('52wkLow', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('changesPercentage', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('avgVol3m', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('avgVol10day', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('avgVol30day', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('sharesOutstanding', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('eps', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('pe', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('pbRatio', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('sma10', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('sma30', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('sma50', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('sma200', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('priceAvg10', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('priceAvg50', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('priceAvg200', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('beta', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('pegRatio', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('dividendYieldPercentage', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('dividendYield', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('payoutRatio', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('ebitda', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('netIncome', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('revenue', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('operatingIncome', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('grossProfit', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('enterpriseValueMultiple', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('evToSales', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('evToOperatingCashFlow', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('evToFreeCashFlow', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('revenuePerShare', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('netIncomePerShare', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('operatingCashFlowPerShare', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('freeCashFlowPerShare', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('earningsYield', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('freeCashFlowYield', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('cashPerShare', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('bookValuePerShare', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('shareholdersEquityPerShare', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('netProfitMargin', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('grossProfitMargin', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('operatingProfitMargin', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('returnOnEquity', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('returnOnAssets', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('returnOnInvestedCapital', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('returnOnCapitalEmployed', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('priceToSalesRatio', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('priceToFreeCashFlowsRatio', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('priceCashFlowRatio', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('priceToOperatingCashFlowsRatio', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('debtToEquity', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('debtToAssets', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('cashFlowToDebtRatio', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('netDebtToEBITDA', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('researchAndDevelopementToRevenue', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('capexToOperatingCashFlow', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('capexToRevenue', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('grahamNumber', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('grahamNetNet', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('commonStockIssued', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('commonStockRepurchased', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('operatingCashFlow', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('freeCashFlow', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('cashAndCashEquivalents', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('totalCurrentAssets', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('totalAssets', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('totalCurrentLiabilities', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('longTermDebt', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('totalLiabilities', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('totalStockholdersEquity', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('totalDebt', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('netDebt', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('rsi', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('adx', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('standardDeviation', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('williams', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('analysisRating', 'varchar(45)', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('bbwidth', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('fiveDayPer', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('monthPer', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''),
 ('yearPer', 'double', 'YES', '', None, '')]
```

Comment: what exactly is UpdateBulk?

Comment: that is not the issue, you construct a insert un a function which we can't see and there is the problem

Comment: @nbk  https://dens.website/howto/update-multiple-rows-mysql

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what the error message means. Does this mean something happened in my script and it tried to insert an inf value? "Unknown column 'inf' in 'field list'"" confuses me because 'inf' is not a column in the table, or a column thats included in the 'var' list.

Comment: @user15436810 i can mysql and sql almost perfectly but i don't know your function

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70159396/error-inserting-values-in-sql-unknown-column-nan-in-field-list/70160049#70160049) is similar: it's for `nan` rather than `inf` but the cause is the same: `nan` is inserted into the query as a number, so it isn't quoted, but the database sees it as a column name because it's an unquoted string.

Answer (score 0):

```py
# table to insert into
table = 'stockStats_dev'
sql = UpdateBulk(var, table, 'ticker')

# ADD THIS
del all_data['inf']

# inserting the data into the table
mycursor.executemany(sql, all_data)

# closing access to the database
mydb.commit()
mycursor.close()
mydb.close()
```