# Error inserting values in SQL: Unknown column 'nan' in 'field list'

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

```
for row in dfp.itertuples():
 cursor.execute('''
             INSERT INTO players (PID, NAME)
             VALUES (%s,%s)
             ''',
                (row.PID,
                 row.NAME)
              )
```

After running this code, I am getting this error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'nan' in 'field list'
```

What should I do to solve this error?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the dataframe contains `NaN` values; when passed to the query `NaN` is not quoted because it's a number, but it gets stringified like this

```sql
INSERT INTO players (PID, NAME) VALUES (1, NaN)
```

and the database interprets the unquoted "string" as a column name and can't find the column.

The solution is to replace or remove such values before writing to the database, for example by using [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#filling-missing-values-fillna) to replace them with some other, suitable value:

```py
for row in dfp.fillna(-1).itertuples():
 cursor.execute('''
             INSERT INTO players (PID, NAME)
             VALUES (%s,%s)
             ''',
                (row.PID,
                 row.NAME)
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert

```
dfp['NAME'] = dfp['NAME'].fillna("---")
```

before for loop, for fill up Nan value with '---'